# $f(x) = f^{-1}(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = x$?

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I recently came across the following property being used to solve some "coffin problems":
$$f(x) = f^{-1}(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = x$$

The intuition given was that $f^{-1}$ is the reflection of $f$ about $y = x$, and hence $f$ and $f^{-1}$ must have the same intersection points as $f$ and $y=x$. (And this property has been used to simplify problems like $\frac{3x^3+1}{2} = (2x-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to $\frac{3x^3+1}{2} = x$.)

**But how do you prove this formally?**

I tried but couldn't prove anything except $f(f(x)) = x$, which is obvious. If you need to make certain assumptions about f like surjectivity, injectivity, continuity, etc, go ahead but do state them clearly. Obviously the weakest assumptions are preferred.

**Edit** There is no implicit forall quantification over $x$ in any equation. The above property should be understood as:
$$\{x \: | f(x) = f^{-1}(x) \} \subseteq  \{x \: | f(x) = x \}$$

Comment: You need something else as a condition, since $f(x)=-x$ works too.

Comment: @dxiv Partly yes. The post there gives counterexamples for general $f$ for which property doesn't hold like $f(x) = -x , \frac{1}{x}$. Another user also shows that if $f$ is assumed to be strictly increasing, the property holds. Is this the weakest assumption known, for which the property holds or can something weaker be found... maybe like strictly monotone?

Comment: Op's statement works if f(x) is an increasing function.

Comment: @ZAhmed increasing or strictly increasing?

Comment: You can, more generally, get lots of functions with this property. Let $h$ be a bijection of $\mathbb R^{+}.$ Then $$f(x)=\begin{cases}-h(x)& x>0\\h^{-1}(-x)&x<0\\ 0&x=0\end{cases}$$ You get continuous such $f$ if $h$ is continuous and $\lim_{x\to0+} h(x)=0.$

Comment: @Kaind Strictly monotonic is not sufficient e.g. $f(x) = -x$ or $f(x) = -x^3$.

Comment: Yes strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

This fails for the simple function $f(x)=-x$. We have $f=f^{-1}$ (they are the same function), i.e., $f(x)=f^{-1}(x)$ for all $x\in {\Bbb R}$, yet $f(x)=x$ only for $x=0$.

More generally any invertible function satisfying $f(f(x))=x$ (of which were are uncountably many) has this property.

Comment: Your second statement is wrong, counterexample - $f(x) = \frac{3x^3+1}{2}$.

Comment: @Kaind ... I do not understand your comment.  The function $f(x) = \frac{3x^3+1}{2}
$ fails both properties: $f(f(x)) = x$ and $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar You're misunderstanding the question. In words, the question says that the intersection points of $y = f(x)$ and $y = f^{-1}(x)$ are the same as $y =f(x)$ and $y=x$. It doesnt say that $f$ is the same function as $f^{-1}$

Comment: For the example $f(x)=-x$ we have $\{x\mid f(x)=f^{-1}(x)\} = {\Bbb R}$, which is not a subset of $\{0\}=\{x\mid f(x)=x\}$. We're only giving examples with $f=f^{-1}$ because they give very blatant examples of the failure of your edited claim/conjecture.